# Is it possible to call constructor from the base class in the child class that includes a parameter of a different type in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, type-conversion

```
public ClassA {
    private int height;

    public ClassA(int firstHeight){
        height = firstHeight; 
    }
}

public ClassB extends ClassA {
    public ClassB(double secondHeight){
        super(secondHeight);
    }
}
```

I know this does not compile due to lossy conversion from int to double but is there any way that I can convert the type without having to create a new double type variable for secondHeight in the child class?

Apologies if this has been ask before, I'm a newbie and am not sure exactly what I'm searching for on this massive platform. Thanks!

Comment: You can explicitly type cast it to `int`: `super((int) secondHeight);`

Comment: Do you need the double value, or are you okay with coercing it to an int?  Is it okay if calling code passes 9.2 and your class treats it as 9?